# Canvas cuts edges of pie chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image]

Like above image,`canvas` cut off the edges of pie chart.I am trying to adjust width and height of canvas.When width is high ,bottom will be cut and when height is high sides will be cut.

Here my code in php for canvas:

```
            printf('<table>');
            echo '<tr><td style="text-align: right;"><canvas id="pie-canvas-'
                 . $canvasId
                 . '" width=256 height=256 style="width=300px;height=300px"></canvas></td><td style="text-align: left;width:360px;" id="legend" class="chart-legend"></td></tr>';

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">drawPie('
                . $canvasId
                . ', '
                . $data
                .', '
                . $legend
                . ');</script>';
```

Javascript:

```
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="django/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>' );
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/jquery-min.js"></script>' );
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript">' );
    ?>
    function drawPie( canvasId, data, legend )
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("pie-canvas-" + canvasId);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var midX = canvas.width/2;
        var midY = canvas.height/2;
        var piedata = [];

        $.each(data,function(i,val){
            piedata.push({value:val.count,color:val.color,label:val.status});
        });

        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata, {
            showTooltips: false,
            onAnimationProgress: drawSegmentValues
        });

        var radius = myPieChart.outerRadius;

        function drawSegmentValues()
        {
            var length = myPieChart.segments.length;
            var totalValue = 0;
            for (var i=0; i< length; i++)
            {
                totalValue +=myPieChart.segments[i].value;
            }
            for(var i=0; i< length; i++)
            {
                ctx.fillStyle="black";
                var textSize = canvas.width/15;
                ctx.font= textSize+"px Verdana";

                // Get needed variables
                var value = Math.round(((myPieChart.segments[i].value)/totalValue)*100);
                var startAngle = myPieChart.segments[i].startAngle;
                var endAngle = myPieChart.segments[i].endAngle;
                var middleAngle = startAngle + ((endAngle - startAngle)/2);

                // Compute text location
                var posX = (radius/1.5) * Math.cos(middleAngle) + midX;
                var posY = (radius/1.5) * Math.sin(middleAngle) + midY;

                // Text offside by middle
                var w_offset = ctx.measureText(value).width/2;
                var h_offset = textSize/4;

                ctx.fillText(value+"%", posX - w_offset, posY + h_offset);
            }
        }

        if(legend)document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = myPieChart.generateLegend();
    }
    <?php
    printf('</script>');
```

Can you tell me how to resolve this and get perfect chart?

Comment: The height and width you need to crap should be equal to your mid[X/Y] - radius. There might be rounding issue here, so if you want pixel perfection you can use pixel data.

Comment: I have given width and height in pixel.But still same problem.Can you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: You could start from the top middle pixel of the canvas (canvas.width/2,0) and loop the Y +1, untill you see that the current pixel is not  grey but white ( the outer circle)

Comment: Can you share any example do to this?